# Method to prevent token splitting with Flex lexical analyser?

Tags: c, parsing, grammar, bison, flex-lexer

Currently using Flex to scan a grammar that defines a subset of C. Here is the .l file.

```
 /*definitions*/
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    int yylex(void);
%}
/*rules*/
%%
"int"                   {printf("TYPE_INT %s\n",yytext);}
"float"                 {printf("TYPE_FLOAT %s\n",yytext);}
"char"                  {printf("TYPE_CHAR %s\n",yytext);}
"bool"                  {printf("TYPE_BOOL %s\n",yytext);}
"while"                 {printf("WHILE %s\n",yytext);}
"do"                    {printf("DO %s\n",yytext);}
"for"                   {printf("FOR %s\n",yytext);}
"printf"                {printf("PRINTF %s\n",yytext);}
"scanf"                 {printf("SCANF %s\n",yytext);}
"if"                    {printf("IF %s\n",yytext);}
"elif"                  {printf("ELIF %s\n",yytext);}
"else if"               {printf("ELSE_IF %s\n",yytext);}
"else"                  {printf("ELSE %s\n",yytext);}
"true"                  {printf("TRUE %s\n",yytext);}
"false"                 {printf("FALSE %s\n",yytext);}
"void"                  {printf("VOID %s\n",yytext);}
"main"                  {printf("MAIN %s\n",yytext);}
"return"                {printf("RETURN %s\n",yytext);}
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]*   {printf("IDENTIFIER %s\n",yytext);}
[-+]?(([1-9][0-9]*)|0)  {printf("INTEGER %s\n",yytext);}
[-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+      {printf("FLOAT %s\n",yytext);}
\"[^\"\n]*\"            {printf("STRING %s\n",yytext);}
","                     {printf("COMMA %s\n",yytext);}
";"                     {printf("SEMICOLON %s\n",yytext);}
"{"                     {printf("LEFT_BRACE %s\n",yytext);}
"}"                     {printf("RIGHT_BRACE %s\n",yytext);}
"("                     {printf("LEFT_PAREN %s\n",yytext);}
")"                     {printf("RIGHT_PAREN %s\n",yytext);}
"["                     {printf("LEFT_BRACKET %s\n",yytext);}
"]"                     {printf("RIGHT_BRACKET %s\n",yytext);}
"-"                     {printf("MINUS %s\n",yytext);}
"+"                     {printf("PLUS %s\n",yytext);}
"*"                     {printf("MULTIPLY %s\n",yytext);}
"/"                     {printf("DIVIDE %s\n",yytext);}
"\\"                    {printf("BACKSLASH %s\n",yytext);}
"%"                     {printf("MODULUS %s\n",yytext);}
"=="                    {printf("EQUALS %s\n",yytext);}
"!="                    {printf("NOT_EQUALS %s\n",yytext);}
"<"                     {printf("LESS_THAN %s\n",yytext);}
">"                     {printf("GREATER_THAN %s\n",yytext);}
"<="                    {printf("LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL %s\n",yytext);}
">="                    {printf("GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL %s\n",yytext);}
"="                     {printf("ASSIGN %s\n",yytext);}
"&&"                    {printf("LOGICAL_AND %s\n",yytext);}
"||"                    {printf("LOGICAL_OR %s\n",yytext);}
"!"                     {printf("LOGICAL_NOT %s\n",yytext);}
[" "|\t|\n|\f|\v]       {printf("WHITESPACE\n");}
.                       {printf("UNRECOGNIZED_CHARACTER %s\n",yytext);}
%%

/*for when we use multipe input files*/
int yywrap(void){
    return 1;
}

/*main driver function that takes */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc<2){
        printf("Usage: %s <input_file_name>\n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Error opening input file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    yyin = fp;
    yylex();
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The issue I have is with certain inputs such as `90.s3` and `232a3`. Instead of getting 'UNRECOGNIZED CHARACTER' as in the last grammar rule, flex splits them apart.
`232a3` becomes

```
INTEGER 232
IDENTIFIER a3
```

and `90.s3` becomes

```
INTEGER 90
UNRECOGNIZED_CHARACTER .
IDENTIFIER s3
```

How should I go about stopping this from happening?

Comment: Please note that functions like `printf` and `scanf` are actual functions in C, not keywords. And `main` is the name of a function like any other, it's not a keyword either. And `else` and `if` are two separate keywords that through the normal rules of C can be placed next to each other, they are not a single keyword and shouldn't be treated as such. And C doesn't really have negative numbers, it has just positive number, that can be modified with the unary `-` operator.

Comment: As for the problem you ask about, the first (`232a3`) is handled by a better lexical rules to require an operator or a space after numbers. The second should also be handled by better rules in the lexer, to require digits after the dot `.` and if there are none then the lexer should not continue with the current lexeme and skip to e.g. lexeme separator like a space. All this is hard to do with a Flex-generated lexer. So you might have to live with the flaws from it, and solve it in the parse to generate syntax errors instead.

Comment: You could also add special rules in the parser to detect these patterns and issue specific errors.

Comment: I would recommend accepting floats that have digits on only one side of the decimal point (as C does), instead of requiring digits on both sides.  Examples: `.5`, `0.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How should I go about stopping this from happening?

There are several alternatives.  Among them,

- you could use patterns with trailing context.  For example, this `INTEGER` pattern recognizes an integer token only where it is immediately followed by the end of the file or a character that is neither a decimal point nor an upper- or lowercase letter:

  ```
  [-+]?(([1-9][0-9]*)|0)/([^.A-Za-z]|<<EOF>>)
  ```
- Or you could [play games with start conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/413484/2402272).
- But **your best option** would probably be to add a pattern to match the unwanted tokens and flag the error.  Example:

  ```
  [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]* { /* IDENTIFIER */ }
  ([1-9][0-9]*)|0       { /* INTEGER */ }
  [0-9]+[.][0-9]*       { /* FLOAT version 1 */ }
  [.][0-9]+             { /* FLOAT version 2 */ }

      /* Used only if it affords a longer match than any of the above: */
  [0-9.][0-9]*[a-zA-Z_.][0-9a-zA-Z_.]*  { /* ERROR */ }
  ```

  Note that this example omits leading `+` and `-` from the patterns for numbers.  They will be matched instead by your existing patterns for the `+` and `-` operators, which is exactly what they are in C.

  Note also that you would need to go to more effort -- possibly more than one error pattern -- if you were supporting the `.` as a member-selection operator as in C.